# perl hash of hashes - for eacy key group inner keys and respective values

Tags: perl

I have a hash of hashes retrieved from json and I am trying to flatten hash, group and print values. That is, for each key1 group all keys and respective values.Trying to achieve this in perl using below code but, it is printing individual values each ID and names but not grouped values. Could you please help me how to group and print keys and values.

Data:

```
VAR1= {
        'ID1' => {'Name1' => {'Address1' => {'Mod1' => ['pol1']}},
                  Name2' => {'Address1' => {'Mod2' => ['pol2']}}},
        'ID2' => {'Name3' => {'Address3' => {'Mod3' => ['pol3']}}},
        'ID3' => {'Name4' => {'Address4' => {'Mod4' => ['pol1, pol2, pol3']}}}
}
```

Expected Output:

```
ID1 => [Name1,Address1,mod1(pol1), Name2,Address1,mod2(pol2)],
ID2 => [Name3,Address3,mod3(pol3)],
ID3 => [Name4,Address4,mod4(pol1,pol2,pol3)]
```

Code1:

```
for my $id (@id_list) {
     foreach my $item (sort (slurp(\%{$new{$id}}))) {
     my $data = join(',', @$item);
     print "data..  $data\n";
     push(@results,$data);
  } 
}

print map {"$_"}  @results;
```

Code2:

```
foreach my $id (sort keys %new){
   foreach my $name (keys %{$new{$id} }) {
      foreach my $address (keys %{$new{$id}{$name}}) {
         foreach my $mod (keys %{$new{$id}{$name}{$address}) {
            foreach my $value (@{$new{$id}{$name}{$address}{$mod}}) {
               my $sp = ":";
               my $reasons = join(',',$id,$name,$address,$mod,$value.$sp);
               push (@rea, $reasons);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your expected output?  What you have seems like a hash, with keys being the original top-level keys and values being array-references -- but "_mod(pol)_" doesn't fit into that.

Comment: @zdim,  If I understand correctly, you are saying that mod(pol) is not key and value. yes you are correct it is set of top level keys and values are list. my $value ((@{$new{$id}{$name}{$address}{$mod}}) is returning the expected "pol" value of respective "mod".

Comment: Your second code is almost right -- it has a missing `}` in `$mod` loop, and it is not assembling all array values in the inner-most loop.  If you want a hash with array-ref, then what exactly is "_mod1(pol1)_"?  Is that meant to be a string with that content, `'mod1(pol1)'`?  What is written is not valid Perl.

Comment: yes "mod1(pol1)" is sting with content ( mod1 = $mod, pol1 = $value).  Please suggest how to assemble all array values in inner-most loop.

Comment: yes, thats correct

Comment: This is a good question in my opinion, but all of this discussion should have been in it to start with.  For the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such a nested structure you want to go systematically, like in your "*Code2*".

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my %id_list = ( 
    ID1 => { 
        Name1 => {'Address1' => {'Mod1' => ['pol1']}}, 
        Name2 => {'Address1' => {'Mod2' => ['pol2']}}
    },  
    ID2 => { 'Name3' => {'Address3' => {'Mod3' => ['pol3']}} },
    ID3 => { 'Name4' => {'Address4' => {'Mod4' => ['pol1, pol2, pol3']}} }
);

my (%flattened, @ar, $modvals);
foreach my $id (sort keys %id_list){
    foreach my $name (keys %{$id_list{$id} }) {
        foreach my $address (keys %{$id_list{$id}{$name}}) {
            foreach my $mod (keys %{$id_list{$id}{$name}{$address}}) {
                $modvals = "$mod(" . 
                    join(',', @{$id_list{$id}{$name}{$address}{$mod}})
                    . ')';
                $modvals =~ s/,$//; # strip the last comma
                push @ar, $name, $address, $modvals;
            }   
        }   
    }
    $flattened{$id} = [ @ar ];
    @ar = ();
}

say "$_ => @{$h{$_}}" for sort keys %flattened;
```

Output

```
ID1 => Name1 Address1 Mod1(pol1) Name2 Address1 Mod2(pol2)
ID2 => Name3 Address3 Mod3(pol3)
ID3 => Name4 Address4 Mod4(pol1, pol2, pol3)
```

This generates the string for `mod3` as `(pol1, ...)` -- as given in input, as a *single* string.  If that is chaged to a list of `pol` in input, the spaces between `pol`'s will be gone in output.

A hash with `id` keys and array ref with respective entries is generated.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the details. Sry if I have confused you.  The output is not grouped at "name" level.  Expected output:                                                                                              ID1=>[Name1,Address1,Mod1(pol1), Name2,Address1,Mod2(pol2) ]            ID2=>[Name3,Address3,Mod3(pol3)]
ID3=>[Name4,Address4,Mod4(pol1, pol2, pol3)]

Comment: no still not grouped. say for example ID1 has name1 and name 2 as unique values with pol1 and pol2 as values.  The output should be          ID1=>[Name1,Address1,Mod1(pol1), Name2,Address1,Mod2(pol2) ]

Comment: ,please let me know if am missing any information on the expected output.

Comment: @Sampath  Note: your input has `['pol1, pol2, pol3']`, as one string.  If these are meant to be three string in an anonumous array, `['pol1', 'pol2', 'pol3']` then rewrite them.  The solution will then assemble that as `pol1,pol2,pol3` (no spaces).

Comment: @Sampath  I would say, instead of "_Expected output_", something like 'I want to build a hash with keys being `id` and values being array references, with such-and-such in them'.  And then in that be careful to quote those strings, `'Name1'`, `'mod1(pol1)'`, etc.  So you can keep what you put there for "Expected output", just make it correct Perl (by quoting all those strings).  It goes without saying that those are really variables, but at least your post has correct Perl. Otherwise it's good, and great that you provided your work.  [Btw: what is `slurp`?]

Comment: excellent, its worked like a charm.  awesome solution, you made my day.  I will work on this to fit my solution by creating a function so that I can re-use this. Also I will customize little to have the output in array format so that I can adding few more details to output.   Once again thank you very much.  I will get back to you in case I come across  any issues

Comment: Zdim, Thanks for correction, sure I will make a note of it. I just tried to use Deep::Hash::Utils for iterating over nested hashes and this package used slurp to return hash reference.

Comment: @Sampath  OK, good. You should explore modules. Then you include that in the post, the `use` line. Let me know if there are further questions.  Complex data structures are needed, of course, and this is good to play with.  However, if you find yourself descending too far into nesting levels it may (or may not) be a sign that the algorithm should be changed.